# Spark - Call Spark jar from java with arguments

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I would like to call spark jar from java (to run spark process on yarn), and try to use this [link](https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/data-algorithms-book/blob/master/misc/how-to-submit-spark-job-to-yarn-from-java-code.md) code.

It looks fit in my case, but I need to pass hashmap and some java values to spakr jar. Is it able to pass java object to spark jar?

And is java side able to know how mush spark jar process or is it done? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the content given in data-algorithms

There are 2 ways to submit job

1) Spark-submit like below example from shell script

```
cat run_secondarysorting.sh

#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk7
export SPARK_HOME=/home/hadoop/spark-1.1.0
export SPARK_MASTER=spark://myserver100:7077
BOOK_HOME=/home/mp/data-algorithms-book
APP_JAR=$BOOK_HOME/dist/data_algorithms_book.jar
INPUT=/home/hadoop/testspark/timeseries.txt
# Run on a Spark standalone cluster
prog=org.dataalgorithms.chap01.spark.SparkSecondarySort
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--class $prog \
--master $SPARK_MASTER \
--executor-memory 2G \
--total-executor-cores 20 \
$APP_JAR
```

2) From Yarn Client which was described in the link.

Usage of Yarn Client is

> want to submit Spark jobs from Java code (such as Java servlets or
>   other Java code such as REST servers).

***When you are calling this yarn client... then you need to call as method in your rest-service or servlet etc... (i.e. through web) in which you can also pass parameters like HashMap or any java object kind...***

**For demo purpose he has written standalone client (with public static void main)**

Hope you understood..

Comment: Since now, I embeded spark jar in core java project and call it with spark main method to pass some object. (and it works well), but as much as file that takes care of in spark as bigger, I thought that satndalone mode is not enough if the file is getting bigger.

Comment: so what is the problem, you want to do it with yarn client via rest-service or servlet ?

Comment: Someday, standalone mode is not enough to do this work. so I would like to make cluster with extra computer machines. yarn is one of my option to do this.

Comment: yes. you are right. was my answer helpful to understand better?

Comment: see this  Standalone mode : This is the default setup. You start the Spark master on a master node and a “worker” on every slave node, and submit your Spark app to the Spark master.
YARN client mode :
In this mode, you do not start a Spark master or worker nodes. Instead, you submit the Spark application to YARN, which runs the Spark driver in the client Spark process that submits the application.
YARN cluster mode In this mode, you do not start a Spark master or worker nodes. Instead, you submit the Spark application to YARN, which runs the Spark driver in the
ApplicationMaster in YARN.

Comment: for webapps Yarn-client mode is better in my opinion.

Comment: Still bit confused. So is the link that I refer ok to use as yarn-client mode if I call method which is passed object arguments?

Comment: if it is `public static void main` i.e `SubmitSparkJobToYARNFromJavaCode ` which uses `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client` you have to execute from command line. then you cant pass java object as arguments, instead you can define your   arguments in property file and load it from `main` method. Otherwise, If its webapplication caller....  then `public static void main` change it to a normal method with java object argument then you can pass java object arguements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130469/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-j-done).

Comment: This is call serquence if you are using web app method SpringMVCService -> method having yarnclient class(which is not public static void main your custom method impl. of SubmitSparkJobToYARNFromJavaCode ) -> your func(_Path: String, _map: HashMap[String, String], _optionMap: HashMap[String, Any]): method