# How to chain multiple jobs in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I would like to know is there a way to chain the jobs in Spark, so the output RDD (or other format) of first job is passed as input to the second job ?

Is there any API for it from Apache Spark ? Is this even idiomatic approach ?

From what I found is that there is a way to spin up another process through the yarn client for example [Spark - Call Spark jar from java with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113712/spark-call-spark-jar-from-java-with-arguments), but this assumes that you save it to some intermediate storage between jobs.

Also there are runJob and submitJob on `SparkContext`, but are they good fit for it ?

Comment: you will have to provide a handle in chaining your jobs which will pass on the computed RDD from each job. To avoid re execution of the DAG of the finally computed RDD , you will have to persist of cache it in memory , let the second job transformations work on that RDD .. unpersist the RDD and do the same operation for the RDD which came as output in second job.

Comment: Spark job =!= Spark application. You can have multiple jobs in an application, [you cannot, in general, share RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27917784/9613318) between applications.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same RDD definition to define the input/output of your jobs.
You should then be able to chain them.

The other option is to use DataFrames instead of RDD and figure out the schema at run-time.